# Setting Width to Parent Width with CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to set a child `<ul>` to  be the same width as its parent `<li>`. The parent `<li>`'s are all varrying width, so I can't just set that to something solid. Is there any way to do this via CSS? Here's what I maen:

What it is:

[image]

What it should be:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `width: 100%`?  Where is the applicable code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just set fixed widths inline to each LI. Not ideal, but usable. Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `width:100%` ?

```
<ul>
 <li>
   <ul style="width:100%">
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That makes it the width of the child LI's for some reason.

Comment: how? It is the width of the parent li. Then mind the paddings and the margins if you perceived the whole li was not filled

Answer (score 0):

You need to first define the box model for that UL.

UL elements have margin and padding values by default. Setting up the UL to margin: 0; and padding: 0 will occupy the 100% of the parent LI.

```
ul li {
 ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
}
```